# uiautomatorviewer - What does NAF stand for?

Tags: android-uiautomator

Its my understanding that UIAutomator is unable to automate any elements where NAF = true in uiautomatorviewer.  Ive searched high and low but i cant for the life of me find what NAF stands for.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"**Not Accessibility Friendly**"

These are UI elements which are apparently interactive, but which don't have accessibility affordances like content descriptions.

From the source for [AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/master/uiautomator/library/core-src/com/android/uiautomator/core/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper.java) (part of uiautomator):

> ```
> /**
>  * We're looking for UI controls that are enabled, clickable but have no
>  * text nor content-description. Such controls configuration indicate an
>  * interactive control is present in the UI and is most likely not
>  * accessibility friendly. We refer to such controls here as NAF controls
>  * (Not Accessibility Friendly)
>  *
>  * @param node
>  * @return false if a node fails the check, true if all is OK
>  */
> private static boolean nafCheck(AccessibilityNodeInfo node) {
>     boolean isNaf = node.isClickable() && node.isEnabled()
>             && safeCharSeqToString(node.getContentDescription()).isEmpty()
>             && safeCharSeqToString(node.getText()).isEmpty();
>     if (!isNaf)
>         return true;
>     // check children since sometimes the containing element is clickable
>     // and NAF but a child's text or description is available. Will assume
>     // such layout as fine.
>     return childNafCheck(node);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 8):

NAF stands for  " Not Accessibility Friendly" .